# Storing 'find -print0' in intermediate variable without losing nul char

Tags: shell, xargs, ash

I have the following sequence of commands to lint JSON files in a directory:

```sh
npm install --global --no-save jsonlint-cli
FILES="$(find . -name '*.json' -type f -print)"
echo -e "Discovered JSON files:\n$FILES"
echo "$FILES" | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs jsonlint-cli
```

I fully realize this is a NO-NO because it does not use the [`-print0 | xargs -0`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) pattern.

However, I would like to **retain the ability to echo the discovered files but also invoke `find` and `jsonlint-cli` only once.**

This is made difficult by the fact that [`ash` can't store `\0` in a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347390/334333).  So this will **not** work:

```sh
FILES="$(find . -name '*.json' -type f -print0)"
echo -e "Discovered JSON files:\n$FILES" | tr '\0' '\n'  # No effect, '\0' already gone
echo "$FILES" | xargs -0 jsonlint-cli
```

How can I use `-print0 | xargs -0` will still maintaining the current behavior of echoing the discovered files to stdout?

The shell in this case is `ash` (inside a `node:alpine` Docker container).

Comment: Worth mentioning the [ash does not support process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28503/334333) / teeing stdout to multiple commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see anything that keeps you from doing it like this:

```
echo 'Discovered JSON files:'
find . -name '*.json' -type f -print -exec jsonlint-cli {} +
```

Note that if you have so many files that find needs to split them into sets, this won't work as you expected.

Comment: Just to be clear, this does make a separate invocation to `jsonlint-cli` for each file found, right? (I'm honestly not sure if that will slow things down at all.)

Comment: @BradSolomon Probably not significantly; the time it takes to actually lint the file should dwarf the time it takes to start the process.

Comment: @oguzismail ah right, I see the `+` on the end.  ("the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files.")